# How to resolve google cloud firestore read and write api error?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a android app connected to firestore database. I don't know why suddenly these two api's of firestore "google.firestore.v1.Firestore.Listen" AND " google.firestore.v1.Firestore.Write" are showing error and my production app is affected extreamly. It is showing that traffic is coming from unspecified api and it also says error by "unspecified" api but I could not figure out the problem. Please help me.
[image: API ERROR SCREENSHOT]

Comment: did you ever manage to figure this out?

Comment: Sorry to say but no. I also created a demo firestore project but the problem occurs there too. So I think that there something else going on..

Comment: I am having the same issue. Could it be an error is thrown when you cancel your listener and setup a new one?

Comment: Same issue here. Have you noticed any related issues in the app itself? My app seems to work normally as far as I know.